# App manager won't add any apps

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I try to add either a packaged or hosted app into app manager on firefox 30. I've verified that the hosted app works on my handset (obviously I have no way of testing that the packaged app works without installing it via app manager, which isn't working). The app then does not show up in the list of apps in app manager (which is empty), nor does firefox display any error messages either as alerts or logs in the console. I went on a hunt for logs around my filesystem, but I couldn't find anything. I am on OSX 10.9.

Comment: Have you tried using Aurora or Nightly?

Comment: Yep, I've tried both. Same thing.

Comment: Do you have the simulator and adb helper addons installed

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how that'd be relevant. It won't add the apps to the list of apps in the app manager, I haven't yet gotten to installing it on a simulator or my device yet.

Comment: can you test with Firefox Nightly and WebIDE (Landed this week): https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/06/webide-lands-in-nightly/

Comment: Ok: the 'open app' button in the UI does nothing. The same in the menu, but the 'open packaged app...' does something at least, it opens a file dialog. Then, when I select the file I get the error "Operation Failed: importing packaged app".

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, appeared that I was running Firefox without write rights. Starting FF with sudo resolved the issue.